# How to update options of select but keep previously selected one as selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my try on implementing this:

```
                var select = document.getElementById(key);
                var temp = select.value;
                select.options.length = 0; // clear out existing items
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    select.options.add(new Option(data.Value, data.Key))
                }
                select.value = temp;
```

In case of there is no such value anymore I would like to set some default values for selcted option.

Comment: If the old value is no longer available, what should the default be? The first item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple function called `init_select`

- It clear the selection tag
  -remembers the option that was previously  selected
- if the item that was previously selected item is not in the list of new options..it will select the option that you want (this is the default_opt) parameter
  -if the previously item is IN  the list it will ignore the default_opt paramater and use the previously selected item.

**demo here (previously selected item NOT in list but default_opt is IN list)**

```js
function init_select(id,data,default_opt) {
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  var temp = select.value;
  select.innerHTML="";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    select.options.add(new Option(data[i]))
  }
  if (data.indexOf(temp) < 0 && data.indexOf(default_opt)>=0 ) {
    select.value = default_opt;
    console.log('this is select',select.value,default_opt,select);
  } else if (data.indexOf(temp) >= 0){
    //select.options.add(new Option(temp));
    select.value = temp;
    console.log(select.value,data.indexOf(temp));
}
}
init_select('key',["New Value", "New Value2", "New Value3", "New Value4"],"New Value2")
```

```html
<select id="key">
  <option>year1</option>
  <option>year2</option>
  <option>year3</option>
</select>
```

**demo here (previously selected item IN  list and default_opt is IN list, default options is ignored and the previously selected item is selected)**

```js
function init_select(id,data,default_opt) {
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  var temp = select.value;
  select.innerHTML="";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    select.options.add(new Option(data[i]))
  }
  if (data.indexOf(temp) < 0 && data.indexOf(default_opt)>=0 ) {
    select.value = default_opt;
    console.log('this is select',select.value,default_opt,select);
  } else if (data.indexOf(temp) >= 0){
    //select.options.add(new Option(temp));
    select.value = temp;
    console.log(select.value,data.indexOf(temp));
}
}
init_select('key',["New Value", "New Value2", "New Value3", "New Value4","year1"],"New Value2")
```

```html
<select id="key">
  <option>year1</option>
  <option>year2</option>
  <option>year3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of getting the value of select and resetting it was right. You can achieve your wanted result with `jQuery` like this.

Note that if the old value is not available, `select`'s value will be set to null.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var def = "4. Option";
  var temp = $("select").val();
  var select = $("select");

  select.empty();
  for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    $("<option>").text(i + ". Option").appendTo(select);
  }
  select.val(temp);

  if (select.val() == null)
    select.val(def);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1. Option</option>
  <option>2. Option</option>
  <option>3. Option</option>
  <option>4. Option</option>
  <option>5. Option</option>
</select>

<button>Clear and Fill Select</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP's code already do this? You've ignored the part about setting some other value as default if the previously selected value no longer exists.